# Why are the font color defined in media queries not having effect?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, bootstrap-4

Why are the font color defined in media queries not having effect? Example,

```
@media (min-width: 576px){
    html {
        color: red !important;
        font-size: 1.2rem;
    }
}
```

font size has effect but not the color even with !important.

This is with Bootstrap 4.

Comment: [Works just fine](https://jsfiddle.net/dcfw8v70/).

Comment: Try using the developer's tool in the web browser to see what styles are being applied; it is quite possible that another style (say for a p tag or body) is overriding the style applied to html.

Comment: They are, you just have something else that overrules the above. `min-width: 576px` is practically the same as "*red if nothing else is defined elsewhere*" ...`!important;` does not help here since you are in the very top of the hierarchy.

Comment: Now it works just need to be more specific with selector thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

if u r making parent color to work then put all the child `color:inherit`
it'll inherit parent color property automatically

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine.

If you're using Chrome browser, right-click on the text > Inspect. On the menu that pops up, under Style tab, look at the color attribute.

[image]